# Package.json reference local package

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs

I have created a library of React components that I reuse in various projects.

In my package.json I reference the library using  file://

"reactcomponents": "file:../reactcomponents",

Everything works fine until I start running a jest tests that references one of these components. I get the error:

Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
  34 | function Toast(props) {
  35 |     var timer = null;
> 36 |     react_1.useEffect(function () {
```

The error is happening because (3) I have another (same) version of react in my react component library and in the main project. If I copy the Toast component into my main project, the project goes away.

The issue is discussed here:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991

How do I get round this?

Comment: I think you need to just use React a dependency in your main project, and list it as a peer dependency in your support projects.

Comment: I have create a simple project that has parent and library (which has peerDependencies) but I cannot get it to work: https://github.com/jmc420/npm_peer_dependencies